# Javascript running more than once when its not intended to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having trouble making this run once, Im not sure what I'm doing wrong as before I added the scroll height effect it worked fine.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 450;

 if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) { 


 $('#coins').lazylinepainter( 
 {
    "svgData": pathObj,
    "strokeWidth": 4,
    "strokeColor": "#8E9CCD"
}).lazylinepainter('paint'); 

}
```

Comment: maybe it's because the scroll event is firing multiple times?

Comment: when you scroll the scroll event will fire a bunch of times typically.

Comment: The `scroll` event is fired lots of times while you're scrolling.  You want to either debounce or throttle it: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: is there a way to make the scroll only fire up once

Comment: @user3097640 No, but you could make the code within it only fire once, however i seriously doubt that's what you really want. At that point you might aswell not have a scroll event at all because it won't keep up with the scrolling.

Comment: @KevinB how would I make the code within fire up once?

Comment: unbinding the scroll event after it happens is one way, but like i said that's not really what you want. Try it and see. `$(window).off("scroll")`

Answer (score 1):

John Resig has a blog post describing how to properly deal with the scroll event being fired multiple times: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Long story short you need to periodically check whether or not the user scrolled and execute your code if they did. Your code should look something like this (taken from same blog post):

```
var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),
    didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        // Check your page position and then
        // Load in more results
    }
}, 250);
```